# Decrypt a string in Python that was encrypted by AES-CBC using crypto.subtle in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, encryption, cryptography

I am dealing with a case where I need to encrypt the payload at client side using JavaScript via AES-CBC algorithm, but later decrypt it in backend using Python. The module used for encryption in JavaScript is crypto.subtle and works with most of the params being in bytes.

In python2 I'm using a module called PyCrypto where the params are mostly in string. This discrepancy is causing issues with decryption and the output I'm getting is not the same as what was encrypted. Please help me find what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code I'm using:

Encryption (JavaScript)

```js
async function encrypt(content, key) {
    var byteKey = new TextEncoder().encode(key);
    var byteContent = new TextEncoder().encode(content);

    // Generate an AES key using the Crypto API
    var AESKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey("raw", byteKey, "AES-CBC", false, ["encrypt"]);
    // Encrypt using AES algorithm
    var encryptedBytes = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
      { name: "AES-CBC", iv: new Uint8Array(16) }, AESKey, byteContent);
    // Convert the encrypted byte array to a Base64 string
    var encryptedBase64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(encryptedBytes)));
    // Return the encrypted string
    return encryptedBase64;
}
```

Example:

```js
encrypt("A sample string", "samplekey1234567").then(res => console.log(res))

OUTPUT: YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw==
```

Decryption (Python)

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def decrypt(content, key):
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, buffer(bytearray(16), 0,16))
    return cipher.decrypt(content)
```

Example:

```py
cipher = AES.new("samplekey1234567", AES.MODE_CBC, buffer(bytearray(16), 0,16))
cipher.decrypt("YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw==".decode("ascii")) # Gives ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length (Why is this not an issue in JavaScript equivalent?)

cipher.decrypt("YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw==        ".decode("ascii"))
OUTPUT: 'H\x15\xeeMZ\xbd\xdaX\xe6U\xe27F\x9a\xb4e' # Not the original string
```

Comment: The Python code seems to be missing the Base64 decoding of the ciphertext.

Comment: Also note that on the Python side unpadding (after decryption is done) does not occur implicitly. PyCryptodome has a [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong here: you are using a seemingly random IV on both sides, and most probably not the same... AES-CBC requires a key and a known IV to work. You need to pass the cipher and the IV to the Python code – which already knows the key. Without that, you're SOL. So your first task is to produce a random IV (never re-use the same IV), and not just use `iv: new Uint8Array(16)`... BEFORE calling `crypto.subtle.encrypt` make a `Uint8Array(16)`, and populate it with something, hopefully random enough. And yes, you need to pass the IV along with the cipher to the server.

```py
cipher.decrypt("YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw==        ".decode("ascii"))
```

Also, another issue that won't help is that you are trying to decrypt Base64, padded with spaces. Lol no. Turn the Base64 content, sans the extra spaces, ie `"YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw=="`, nothing else, back to a stream of bytes (make sure binascii didn't add a spurious `\n` at the end), and decrypt THAT.

```py
>>> cipher = AES.new(b"samplekey1234567", AES.MODE_CBC, bytearray(16))
>>> cipher.decrypt(binascii.a2b_base64((b"YZGjFFgnngBBBTSm8euZEw==").decode("ascii")))
b'A sample string\x01'
```

[In this case, since you used an empty buffer on both sides, ie 16 zeroes, I could reproduce your example and decrypt. But, as I said, do not use, and pass, non-random IVs, and never twice the same one].

I'm using Python3 – and so should you. So I am using `bytes` instead of strings, but the concept remains the same. The last byte, `\x01`, is padding. Since AES encodes blocks of 16 bytes, it will add the number of remaining, "empty", characters at the end of the block to make it 16. In this case, 'A sample string' is 15 bytes, so it added `0x01`. You might want to encode the string terminator, `0x00`, so that Python knows where the string stops...